# Redirecting printf on iOS to user interface

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, multithreading, pipe

I'm new to iOS development (and Obj-C), and I'm trying to port an existing C program to iOS.

The C program usually runs in the console, but I want to make a UI for it on the iPhone. I've already ported the C code, and when the simulator is run I can get the printf output in the console window. I want to avoid changing the original code as much as possible, so this is my plan:

1. The program takes some time to execute, so I think I need to run it on a seperate thread. It look likes I'll only need an NSInvocationOperation to call it's main method.
2. I will redirect stdout to a pipe.
3. On another thread, I will read from the pipe, and throw this to the UI. I'm not sure what might be the best concurrancy API to use for this.

Is this a good strategy for the iOS, or is there a better alternative for porting this? Are there any pitfalls I should look out for?

Comment: Jailbreak your iPhone, grab MobileTerminal and run inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For concurrency, use the dispatch queues for quickest programming. [See this guide: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

To print to the screen, you could do this in many different ways, but just use a `UILabel` if you just want get text up there right away. You can also format it nicely later.

Main pitfalls for multithreading are like on any OS - locking any data models that have simultaneous read/write. You can use `@synchronize` or make your dispatch queues thread safe by using `dispatch barriers` also noted in the linked guide above.

Comment: I suppose the main thing I'm wondering about is the strategy to redirect printf output to the label. I could search through the code and replace every printf with a another function that pushes it to the screen; but I am looking for the most modular solution that doesn't change the original code much.

Comment: I'd change the label to a UITextView (which you can scroll so it gets pretty big), and provide some method in the viewController that owns it to update the text. You have to essentially get the old text, append the next text, then update the textView. You can also keep the last bit of text visible using scrollRangeToVisible:. I'd put this in a method on the viewController so you can let any caller message it, and you could use that method to insure the updates are done on the main thread.

Comment: agree with David that if you have lots of text you could use UITextView instead of UILabel, though UILabel also supports multi-line text if you choose to do it that way